# Exponential and Q matrice question

Tags: matrices

For any matrix $Q$, show that  $$\det(e^{Q})=e^{\operatorname{tr}Q}$$

where tr represents the trace and det is the determinant

Comment: Reduce $Q$ to Jordan form.

Comment: As a startinmg point: If $Q$ is a diagonal matrix then an eigenvector of $Q$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ is eigenvektor of $e^Q$ with eigenvalue $e^\lambda$. Therefore the product of eigenvalues of $e^Q$ is the exponential of the sum of eigenvalues of $Q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WLOG Assume that $Q$ is upper triangular with eigenvalues $\lambda_i$'s.Then $Q^k$ is also upper triangular with eigenvalues $\lambda_i^k$. Thus,$e^Q=\sum \frac{Q^k}{k!}$ is also upper triangular with diagonal entries as $e^{\lambda_i}$.

Now just take determinants and we are done.